# Update unique nested array element in Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a very simple example from [official documentation page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/):

Data:

```
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] }
```

I want to update *quantity* where *item = "journal"* *and warehouse = "A"*.

**Item is always unique, warehouse is always unique within array elements.**

For example I tried queries like this:

```
collection.updateOne(
"{ \"item\": \"" + item + "\", \"instock.warehouse\": \"" + warehouse + "\" } } }", // find
"{ $set: { quantity: \"" + quantity + "\" } }" // update
)
```

Issue is always the query, for example this query returns all elements... I tried about 100 different other ones but nothing is working.

I am using embedded db for tests right now from flapdoodle, version 3_4.

Comment: @Gibbs works, thanks a lot! I left a comment but seems it was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use positional operator

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pqPdV98sWz_)

```
db.collection.update({
"instock.warehouse": "C",
  "item": "journal"
},
{
  $set: {
    "instock.$.qty": 10
  }
})
```